# How to get Hexadecimal input and convert it to decimal?

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` where the user types an Hexadecimal number and I want to convert it into a decimal number and show it on a `TextView`, but I can't even show the hexadecimal number on the `TextView` because of an exception: "unable to parse 'String' as integer.
I only can show numbers on the `TextView`. when I type characters it throws the exception.

Here is a piece of the code:

```
EditText edText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
result.setText(""+ Integer.parseInt(edText1.getText().toString(), 16));
```

Comment: so what is the text that you are trying to parse?

Comment: content of edText1 may contain letters because hexadecimal can contain letter and you cant convert letters to integer

Comment: the text is already set in the edText1 (keyboard input) and it contains numbers and characters from a to f

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like you are getting an error because of the initial case of the `edText1.getText()`. When the `textfield` is empty it still stores a value - `""`. `""` is still a `String` and still has contents, yet it is not an integer. So, when you're doing `Integer.parseInt()` on it it's doing somthing like below:

```
result.setText("" + Integer.parseInt("", 16));
```

`""` is clearly not an integer or hexadecimal, yet it is still a `String` so it's having a problem formatting that, then throwing the error.

Comment: Ok, I didn't say that when I put
    result.setText(""+ Integer.parseInt(edText1.getText().toString(), 16));

the edText1 already contains some text the user inputs, e.g. "10AE"
When I put some string instead of edText1.getText().toString() the app works! For example, if I put:
    result.setText(""+ "10e", 16));
the result TextView shows '270' and it's ok. Help please!